# Is there any way to define invalid enum value in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, invalidargumentexception

I have a model as:

```
class CashPayment < ActiveRecord::Base

 .....

 **enum status: [:processing, :paid, :invalid,:refund]**
end
```

Here,I have declared invalid status for cash_payment.But its giving me as error like:

```
*** ArgumentError Exception: You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "CashPayment", but this will generate a instance method "invalid?", which is already defined by Active Record
```

Answer (score 0):

`invalid?` is already defined by `ActiveRecord` .

Your enum `status` also contains `:invalid` which provides a method as `invalid?`

Now there is a conflict while generating two `invalid?` method.

Try to give another name to your `:invalid`, say `:invalid_rec`

```
enum status: [:processing, :paid, :invalid_rec,:refund]
```